# Hover Overlay on Background-Image using Bootstrap and Image Grid

Tags: html, css

My problem is as follows:

- I want to add an Image Overlay when the customer is hovering over an Image-Box.
- The Image is implemented as a Background-Image.
- Bootstrap is giving auto margin which makes my overlay bigger than the picture
- After deleting the padding and adding the space between the image boxes with  margin the responsiveness doesn't work anymore

Question: How can I add the coloured overlay to my image boxes, while keeping the responsiveness and the gap between the images. As you can see: The image boxes don't adapt to col-xs-6, after changing the screen size. They stay in 4 columns.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');


.produkt-img {
  padding-bottom: 133.33333%; 
  background-size: cover;
}

.produkt-1 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x800/fc0');
}

.produkt-2 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x800/fc0');
}

.produkt-3 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x800/fc0');
}

.produkt-4 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x800/fc0');
}
             
        
        
.produkt-box-overlay-text {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
        
        
.produkt-overlay:before{
  position: absolute;
  content:" ";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: none;
  z-index:0;
}

.produkt-overlay:hover:before{
  display: block;
}

.overlay-farbe:before {
/* grauer overlay background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.05)*/
 background-color: rgba(199, 87, 36, 0.1);
}
        
.col-sm-3, produkt-width {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0.5%;
    width: 23.75%;
        }
               
        
.col-sm-3 extra-margin {
    margin-left:1%;  
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 produkt-width produkt-overlay overlay-farbe">
     <div class="produkt-img produkt-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 produkt-width produkt-overlay overlay-farbe">
     <div class="produkt-img produkt-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 produkt-width produkt-overlay overlay-farbe">
    <div class="produkt-img produkt-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 produkt-width produkt-overlay overlay-farbe">
     <div class="produkt-img produkt-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: at your css -->.col-sm-3, produkt-width <-- you defined the width, that's why col-xs-6 not working

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using background images instead of using `<img>` you can use your overlay via pseudo elements on the element that is using the background image. Move the following classes, `.produkt-overlay` and `.overlay-farbe`, from the column elements to the background element. You could also just merge some of the properties from those classes into the `.produkt-img` class if you want to streamline things.

**Note:** I noticed you tried changing the width of the Bootstrap columns and replacing padding with margin. Be careful when you make these changes. There's a reason Bootstrap did what they did and is intended to work in a certain way. Not knowing some of the hows and whys of Bootstrap it's easy to go astray when modifying what they've done.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.produkt-img {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 133.33333%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.produkt-1 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x800/fc0');
}

.produkt-2 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x800/fc0');
}

.produkt-3 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x800/fc0');
}

.produkt-4 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x800/fc0');
}

.produkt-overlay:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 0;
}

.produkt-overlay:hover:before {
  display: block;
}

.overlay-farbe:before {
  background-color: rgba(199, 87, 36, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="produkt-img produkt-overlay overlay-farbe produkt-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="produkt-img produkt-overlay overlay-farbe produkt-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="produkt-img produkt-overlay overlay-farbe produkt-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="produkt-img produkt-overlay overlay-farbe produkt-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The responsiveness is broken because of the invalid css:

```
.col-sm-3, produkt-width
.col-sm-3 extra-margin
```

Here is amended css for the overlay (attached only the changed lines):

```
.produkt-overlay:before{
  left: 15px; /*gutter width*/
  width: calc(100% - 30px); /*gutter width multiplied by 2*/
}
```

[The complete example](http://www.bootply.com/uK0jJx96KQ)